# Custom borders using HTML/CSS with basic HTML

Tags: html, css

I am using TCPDF, which has issues with normal HTML/CSS.  It accepts a basic set of HTML/CSS and unfortunately nothing really fancy.

I need a way to create custom dashed lines, as below:

[image]

Seeing how CSS only has border property of solid, dashed, or dotted, I am lacking the "other way" of dashed lines.  I need to be able to control the length of the stroke, and the length of the in-between space.  So for example stroke length of 17, and in-between space of 5.

How can I do this?  Can I do this?

So far looking at other questions did not help me.  I've read a few questions and none of the solutions so far helped.  Either it's too fancy (tcpdf ignores it), or it resorts back to dashes and dotted properties and those are not sufficient for my purpose.

Comment: There are also `double`, `groove`, `ridge`, `inset`, and `outset`.  There's no way that I know of to easily do this in a way that a PDF creator would also be able to understand. I'd be interested in this, as well.

Comment: you can create a draw line function yourself that will read 2 values both dash length and space length, and the function would then find the current content y value then draw small lines and then stop when it teaches x =0 or whatever page margin you set. Not sure if this helps..

Comment: I'd be interested in this solution too, if there is one. The best thing i could come up with is not even good enough to merit an answer, but you could style a table to appear as a dashed border, with custom widths. i used `:nth-child`, but you could just add classes to alternating cells. vertical borders would be harder than horizontal, too. http://jsfiddle.net/mntux9ec/1/

Comment: I can't really begin to describe what it would involve, but I wonder if you could manage some sort of smart-polyfill using an SVG element. Doing that actually managed to fix some of the border-rendering bugs we were getting in IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a library which doesn't implement CSS's more useful features (such as custom dashed borders, image borders or CSS gradients) **and** because you're writing HTML+CSS solely to generate a a PDF document then I see no problem writing non-semantic HTML using old-school techniques such as `<table>`-abuse to produce an image border.

I suggest using a 9-grid:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="topLeftCorner.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td background="horizontalDottedBorder.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="topRightCorner.gif" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td background="verticalDottedBorder.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>content!</td>
        <td background="verticalDottedBorder.gif">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="botLeftCorner.gif" alt="" /></td>
        <td background="horizontalDottedBorder.gif">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><img src="botRightCorner.gif" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**BIG SCARY WARNING:** Never use this markup in a HTML document viewed in an actual web-browser.

...with the possible exception of HTML email targeting Office Outlook 2007-2013, which is still awful: http://fixoutlook.org/ and https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3769/a-designers-guide-to-outlook-2013

(disclaimer: I work for Microsoft but not on the Office team and these opinion is my own and not that of the company's and stuff)

Comment: all good points, will work if pdf renders images (some are svg-only, others are even more specific). would still be interested in a HTML/CSS solution but this is a possible solution for sure.

Comment: If you can do without HTML/CSS have a look at [TCPDF::SetLineStyle](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d9b3717cd9ad8db31642155c832d148)

Comment: SetLineStyle may work.. although the way my code is now, I draw the table by pulling HTML as a template, so the HTML is already there.  I think using images is my best bet at this time.  TCPDF does seem to allow you to draw such lines if you are using TCPDF to draw the table (without existing template)

Comment: sooo .. it looks like TCPDF does provide some ways to do things its own way, such as using SetLineStyle, as well as other cool magic, but it does so using its own functions, which have to be called in order, as-you-go, and cannot really be mixed with separation of concerns concept such as templating (at least I didn't see a way); and so I did not look deeply into that, because using PNG image files seems to work fine, and it also lets me keep my HTML template in a separate file, and just populate it with the stuff I want, like the `<img>` tags.  Accepting this answer, because of `<img>`

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in TCPDF/tcpdf.php (the main file) called getCSSBorderDashStyle . You can set there different styles.

It is looking like

```
switch (strtolower($style)) {
            case 'none':
            case 'hidden': {
                $dash = -1;
                break;
            }
            case 'dotted': {
                $dash = 1;
                break;
            }
            case 'dashed': {
                $dash = 3;
                break;
            }
            case 'double':
            case 'groove':
            case 'ridge':
            case 'inset':
            case 'outset':
            case 'solid':
            default: {
                $dash = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $dash;
```

By updating the $dash variable you can set the width and space between dots/lines(call them as you wish). Having $dash = 2 it is almost identical to the dots border. I am attaching examples below:

Dash 2
[image]
Dash 5
[image]
Dash 15
[image]
Dash 50
[image]

You can experiment with that and probably get results closer to what is expected. I am setting them in the css for the PDF (on top in head)

```
<html>
            <head>
            <style type="text/css">
            .dashed_div
            {
                border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; 
                width:100%; 
                text-align:right;
                font-size: 12px;
            }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a data:base64 string created by JavaScript as the src value of the image?

Comment: thanks.  can you give an actual example?  i.e. a bit code how that works in a `<td>...</td>`?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @calvinf: This isn't a new question, this is a suggested way to answer the problem. It's not a _great_ answer, because it doesn't provide any detail, or any pointers to the asker to find them on his own, but it's not a question.